# Get selected latest 10 docs from couchDB order by timestamp

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, couchdb

When I run the below view I am getting docs order by time. But if I call URL like below by passing specific device_sno its not working.....

View :

```
function(doc){
    emit([doc.device_sno,doc.timestamp],doc);
}
```

URL :

```
http://localhost:5984/trip_test/_design/test/_view/test?key=["Axe001"]&limit=10&ascending=true&include_docs=true
```

I need to get last 10 records whose `device_sno` is `Axe001` order by timestamp!

Can anyone help me to solve this issue, it would be great help to me. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
http://localhost:5984/trip_test/_design/test/_view/test?start_key=["Axe001"]&limit=10&end_key=["Axe001", {}]
```

That will give you the first 10 items. To get the last 10, do:

```
http://localhost:5984/trip_test/_design/test/_view/test?end_key=["Axe001"]&limit=10&start_key=["Axe001", {}]&descending=true
```

Putting `key` would force it to match that specific key, which isn't the case because the keys have two elements.